# Why does Newtonsoft.Json cause a FileNotFoundException in mscorlib.dll?

Tags: json.net, mscorlib

Building a Windows console OpenAPI application and testing in VS IDE debug mode, the following code does not generate the following error, but attaching to the application process after starting the app the exception does occur.

> System.Lazy<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings>(CreateSerializerSettings, true);

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Part of the problem seems that the installed NUGET is v13.0.3.0, but there is no v13.0.0.0 available.

[image]

I expect either the newer version to be accepted or the specified version of the NUGET to be available.

Also, note that same NUGET and Swagger API code is being used in two different apps on different OS's. The PC Windows 11 Enterprise v22H2 has the issue. The Azure App Service Windows .NET ASP website does not.

Comment: I also tested on both PC and Hyper-V devices with Windows 10 Pro v22H2 and had the same results.

Comment: I discovered that the error message was actually reporting correctly as to the FileNotFoundException of the Newtonsoft.Json file. For some reason the DLL was not merged with the other NuGet packages. I found that if I placed the file in the same deployment folder as the EXE, the file was found and the called function executed properly. It appears that there is an issue with the build process. The problem is more extensive in a .NET 8 build with more components needing to be placed in the deployment folder.

Comment: Note that the assembly version for `NewtonSoft.Json.dll` in the 13.0.x NuGet packages are *all* `13.0.0.0`. Why the assembly version and the NuGet package versions aren't consistent is unknown.